# Which approach best suits vector encodings?

Tags: neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, models

I want to build a model that when given two vectors, outputs the probability of one vector being the encoded form of the other. I have 2 strategies for this: (**Dataset available**)

1. I can directly feed them in concatenation to a neural network and take the output as the probability.
2. I can train a conditional GAN with the conditional vector being the encoded vector and using the original vector as the generated one. In this case, the discriminator works as the network that I train in the first approach.

Which approach is better? Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: I haven't dealt with vector encodings, but I would suggest changing the title of your post to be more relevant. Maybe something like "What model best suits vector encoding classification"

Comment: Okayy! I'll do that